# Non-uniform version for the whole polynomial hierarchy

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, polynomial-hierarchy

The non-uniform versions of P, NP and coNP are P/poly, NP/poly and coNP/poly. 
Similarly, we can define a non-uniform version for each level in the PH.

For example: $\Sigma_2$/poly consists of problems of the form $\{x : \exists y \forall z \; C(x,y,z)\}$, where C is a circuit of polynomial size that may vary depending on the length of the input string $x$, and $y,z$ also have lengths polynomial in $x$.

Doing this for all levels of PH, we get a non-uniform version PH/poly.

QUESTIONS:  Is there anything known about this hierarchy? Does it collapse? Or is there another name for it in the literature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, sure, we know things. I think this is a pretty standard nomenclature for it. This hierarchy collapses if and only if $\mathsf{PH}$ does, exercise:

- For one direction, modify the proof of Karp-Lipton to show that if $\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{coNP}/poly$ then $\mathsf{PH}$ collapses, and observe that this result relativizes
- For the other direction, see the comments by Kaveh below.

Comment: Can $\mathsf{PH}$ collapse but $\mathsf{nuPH}$ not collapse?

Comment: @Daniel, I think you can get rid of the quantifiers uniformity in the circuit, so yes, if PH collapses them so does nuPH.

Comment: @Kaveh: How? I may be being slow, but I don't see it yet...

Comment: Assume P=NP. Consider L in PH/poly. Let's assume L $\in$ $\Sigma^P_k$/poly, that is $\chi_L(x) = \chi_{L'}(x,f(|x|))$ for some advice function f $\in$ poly and L' is in $\Sigma^P_k$. But L' is in P, therefore L is in P/poly.

Comment: Is the notation $\textsf{nuPH}$ used anywhere else? I am not very familiar with how computer scientists name things.

Comment: I made it up. (However, the notation $\mathsf{nuPPT}$ -- meaning "non-uniform probabilistic polynomial-time" -- has been used in a handful of theory of cryptography papers.. There's nothing particularly special about the notation; I mean what you mean. :-))

Comment: PH/poly is certainly the standard notation. I’ve never seen the nu prefix.

Comment: I think I have seen nu prefix before but don't recall where.

Comment: Probably better to stick with $\mathsf{PH/poly}$ :D